# Visual Studio 2019 Remove instant highlighting by clicking

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, syntax-highlighting

I want to know how to turn OFF the occurrence highlighting with a mouse click on Visual Studio 2019. It happens as soon as I click on any word/symbol and it is honestly getting on my nerves. The only thread of this case here on StackOverFlow was unanswered. [Visual Studio 2019 how to disable occurrence highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766837/visual-studio-2019-how-to-disable-occurrence-highlighting)

Can anyone please help me get rid of this issue? It was working just fine before and I don't know what key binding I accidentally clicked/touched. I would be thankful.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Tools</kbd>  <kbd>Options</kbd>  <kbd>Text Editor</kbd>  <kbd>C#</kbd>  <kbd>Advanced</kbd>  <kbd>Highlighting</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response. I have spent a good deal of time looking for this. This solved it.

Comment: I wish they used the (more _correct_) term "caret" instead of "cursor" - because "caret" refers to the text-insertion-point while "cursor" can refer to that as well as the mouse-cursor.

Comment: You can roll back if you like, i just like the button markdown

Comment: Yes, I have been searching for an hour online after looking through VS tools and options and every search criteria shows either cursor or keyboard bindings. This was a life saver. Thank you again.

Comment: @00110001 Ooooh, thank you, actually - I used to use `<kbd>` a lot back when I started on SO, but then they removed it or restyled it to be ugly - then I stopped using it - that must have been a decade ago now :O - I'm glad it's back now.